# Secret login Password - Android

Tags: java, android, start-activity

The goal of my code is: when I type a secret username and password, then, press enter button, open a Activity3. otherwise, open Activity2. This is my code:
    package edcomp.terraraimoveis;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Principal extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    // UI references.
    private AutoCompleteTextView userName;
    private EditText mPasswordView;
    private TextInputLayout nameLayout;
    private TextInputLayout passLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_principal);

        userName = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.username);
        //populateAutoComplete();
        mPasswordView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        nameLayout = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.namelayout);
        passLayout = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.passlayout);
        Button entrarBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.entrarbtn);
        entrarBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        if(validateData() == true){
            if(vipPass() == true){
                Intent myintent = new Intent(Principal.this, AdicionarCredenciais.class);
                Principal.this.startActivity(myintent);
            }else {
                Intent myintent = new Intent(Principal.this, DoisAtividade.class);
                Principal.this.startActivity(myintent);
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean validateData(){
        String nome = userName.getText().toString();
        String pass = mPasswordView.getText().toString();

        boolean result = true;

        if(nome == null){
            nameLayout.setError(getString(R.string.error_invalid_name));
            result = false;
        }else{
            nameLayout.setErrorEnabled(false);
        }

        if(pass == null || pass.length() < 8){
            passLayout.setError((getString(R.string.error_invalid_password)));
        result = false;
        }
        return result;
    }

    public boolean vipPass() {
        String nome = userName.getText().toString();
        String pass = mPasswordView.getText().toString();

        boolean vip_mode = false;
        if (nome == "VIPUSER" && pass == "987654321") {
            vip_mode = true;
        }
        return vip_mode;
    }
}
```

I've added (activity android:name=".AdicionarCredenciais") and (activity android:name=".DoisAtividade") in manifest.xml. But, when I type the secret username and secret pass, then press Enter button, the next activity is not that I want.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java

Answer (score 0):

The problem is slightly within your if statement, Try this:

```
 import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Principal extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    // UI references.
    private AutoCompleteTextView userName;
    private EditText mPasswordView;
    private TextInputLayout nameLayout;
    private TextInputLayout passLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_principal);

        userName = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.username);
        //populateAutoComplete();
        mPasswordView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        nameLayout = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.namelayout);
        passLayout = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.passlayout);
        Button entrarBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.entrarbtn);
        entrarBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        if(validateData() == true){
                          Intent myintent = new Intent(Principal.this, AdicionarCredenciais.class);
                Principal.this.startActivity(myintent);
            }else  
if(vipPass() == true){
                Intent myintent = new Intent(Principal.this, DoisAtividade.class);
                Principal.this.startActivity(myintent);
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean validateData(){
        String nome = userName.getText().toString();
        String pass = mPasswordView.getText().toString();

        boolean result = true;

        if(nome == null){
            nameLayout.setError(getString(R.string.error_invalid_name));
            result = false;
        }else{
            nameLayout.setErrorEnabled(false);
        }

        if(pass == null || pass.length() < 8){
            passLayout.setError((getString(R.string.error_invalid_password)));
        result = false;
        }
        return result;
    }

    public boolean vipPass() {
        String nome = userName.getText().toString();
        String pass = mPasswordView.getText().toString();

        boolean vip_mode = false;
        if (nome == "VIPUSER" && pass == "987654321") {
            vip_mode = true;
        }
        return vip_mode;
    }
}
```

Method 2:

Go to Both of the activities and check if you did set the content view to the correct layout, you might have used the same layout for both activity.

Comment: I think that "nome" and "pass" if is a vipPass() true, it is a validateData() true too. so that, "VIPUSER" and "987654321" satisfies validateData() conditions too.

Comment: Just put vippass() first that validatedata(), in if statement.

Answer (score 0):

try with this code

```
public boolean vipPass() {
        String nome = userName.getText().toString();
        String pass = mPasswordView.getText().toString();

        if (nome.equals("VIPUSER") && pass.equals("987654321")) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```